# Distributions: recommendations. Friedlander versus Duistermaat

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, distribution-theory

I'm trying to learn something about the distribution theory, but since I'm new to the subject I'd like to get some information about what I need to know to understand it in depth. As a Physics student, I have a good (at least, for what it's required for my studies) knowledge of real and complex analysis; however, having read a few pages of Duistermaat's book, *[Distributions: theory and applications](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780817646721)*, I feel that there's something else I should know and that is lacking. My impression seems to be confirmed by Michael Berg's [review](http://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/distributions-theory-and-applications). I've read good opinions about Friedlander's *[Introduction to the theory of distributions](https://books.google.it/books/about/Introduction_to_the_Theory_of_Distributi.html?id=9O-pXIVUEFMC&redir_esc=y)*, but it seems too dry to me and the lack of solutions for the exercises drives against its use for self-study. 
At the moment I'm not able to borrow/buy any other book, so I have to choose one of those books, or both, as a reference, both for the theory and for the exercises and I need your help. Would you recommend Duistermaat's book for a first study? What about Friedlander's *Introduction*? What are the required prerequisites to grasp most of the subject?

---

I know a similar question [has already been asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13711/distribution-theory-book/597147#597147), but I'd like to focus just on a couple of books.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1799914/distribution-for-function/1801060#1801060

Comment: @JohnMartin thank you very much! Somehow I couldn't find that question, even though I did use the search bar.